# How to evaluate the avalanche effect?

Tags: avalanche

How can avalanche effect be calculated? I would in particular want to know what platform or IDE can be used to calculate the same?

Comment: There is also a good answer @ https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41752/can-the-statistical-width-of-the-avalanche-effect-be-calculated/41753?s=4|3.6377#41753 about calculating it theoretically for comparison with experimental results.