# Strict Avalanche Criterion and Avalanche criterion?

Tags: encryption, avalanche

What is the difference between Strict Avalanche Criterion(SAC) and Avalanche criterion?

Comment: **What research have you done?** What were your findings? Why didn't you findings satisfy your needs? For more infos, read [***How do I ask a good question?***](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 9):

The definition of avalanche effect is given in the paper of Webster, A. F. ["On the design of S-boxes". Advances in Cryptology - Crypto '85](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F3-540-39799-X_41#page-1) as :

> For a given transformation to exhibit the avalanche effect, **an average of one half of the output bits should change whenever a single input bit is complemented**.

It is also seen as **each bit should have 50% chances to change if you change 1 bit of the input**. (strict avalanche)

---

In the **avalanche criterion** you look at the **output as a whole** (average 50% of the bits changes).

In the **strict avalanche criterion**, you look at **each bit one by one** and you verify that what ever the other bits will change, it will have a 50% probability to switch.

Related questions:

- [Hash functions and the Avalanche effect](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/40268/hash-functions-and-the-avalanche-effect/40271#40271)
- [Calculation of the avalanche effect coefficient](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34269/calculation-of-the-avalanche-effect-coefficient)

Comment: Unless you specifically code an algorithm to do something extremely weird, does not avalanche = strict avalanche in all practical regards for a grown up candidate hash function?

Comment: No. For example you can have a look at the aes s box. The strict criterion is not here. And to check it on hash candidates you would need too much time.

Answer (score 3):

Avalanche criterion, or Avalanche effect is informal. Small changes in inputs should always lead to large changes in outputs.

Consider a vector Boolean function $$f:F_2^n \rightarrow F_2^m$$ with $n$ bit input and $m$ bit output.

Strict Avalanche Criterion (SAC) says that if any input bit is flipped then exactly half of output bits should change. There are higher order versions as well where $k$ input bits are flipped and the same property is required of the output bits.

Comment: `The strict avalanche criterion (SAC) is a formalization of the avalanche effect. It is satisfied if, whenever a single input bit is complemented, each of the output bits changes with a 50% probability.`

it does not say that exactly half of the bits changes, it says each bit have 50% changes. One bit could change and all the other bits could stay the same. Very unlikely but it is possible.

Comment: @Biv, thanks for the clarification, I was obviously remembering wrong.