# How many $S$-Boxes of length $3$ are there over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$?

Tags: block-cipher, s-boxes

Is there a simple way if counting the number of $S$-Boxes of length $\ell$ over $\mathbb{F}_{2}$? By $S$-box I mean an $S$-box satisfying the avalanche condition.

I mean it is quite easy to see that for  $\ell=2$ the answer is $0$ but I want to know if there is a general formula, specifically for $\ell=3$?

Comment: What are the requirements of an S box?

Comment: I don't get the question. It states _"for $\ell=2$ the answer is $0$"_; but isn't $S(x_0,x_1)=x_0\mathbin|x_1$ _"satisfying the avalanche condition"_ and even the [Strict](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/42471/555) Avalanche Criterion?

Answer (score 2):

By definition, an S-box usually assumed to be *one-to-one*. From your question, you want it to be a fixed bitlength, say $n.$ So it is a one to one mapping from $\{0,1\}^n$ to itself, i.e., a permutation on $2^n$ point. This is usually referred to as an $n\times n$ S-box. There are $2^n!$ such mappings. You can use Stirling's formula or compute this for small $n.$

For example $$2^3!=2^3(2^3-1)\cdots 2\cdot 1=40320.$$

The question becomes more interesting and quite complex if we consider some S-boxes to be equivalent from a cryptographic point of view. For example let our S-box input be $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ and output be $(y_1,y_2,y_3).$ One could argue that relabeling these gives you the same S-box. It gets quite complicated once we start thinking of counting distinct S-boxes under other equivalences.

Thinking of linear cryptanalysis for example, one might say, all $n\times n$ S-boxes which behave the same under analysis given by pre- and post-multiplication by non-singular $n\times n$  matrices and addition of constants at input and output are equivalent.

A nice paper addressing a lot of this is Saarinen, *Cryptographic analysis of all $4\times 4$ S-boxes* available [here](https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/218.pdf)

Comment: I doubt the question is about one-to-one S-boxes, for it (now) states _"satisfying the avalanche condition"_. I still find no way to read the question such that _"for $\ell=2$ the answer is $0$"_ is correct.